# HTML/CSS YES/NO Slider shows more fields when yes is selected

Tags: html, css, web-applications, slider, web-deployment

I'm rather new to web development and would appreciate any help i can get. I have an HTML/CSS slider and I'm wanting to show more txt box fields when the slider is in the yes position like first name and subject. I would really like the options to be based off of another drop down menu if possible. How can I do this?

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF 25px);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF 25px);
  border-radius: 18px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px white, inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.switch-input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.switch-label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: inherit;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #eceeef;
  border-radius: inherit;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.switch-label:before,
.switch-label:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -.5em;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-transition: inherit;
  -moz-transition: inherit;
  -o-transition: inherit;
  transition: inherit;
}

.switch-label:before {
  content: attr(data-off);
  right: 11px;
  color: #aaaaaa;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.switch-label:after {
  content: attr(data-on);
  left: 11px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  opacity: 0;
}

.switch-input:checked~.switch-label {
  background: #0088cc;
  border-color: #0088cc;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.switch-input:checked~.switch-label:before {
  opacity: 0;
}

.switch-input:checked~.switch-label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.switch-handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF 40%, #f0f0f0);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 40%, #f0f0f0);
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.switch-handle:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -6px 0 0 -6px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF);
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
}

.switch-input:checked~.switch-handle {
  left: 74px;
  box-shadow: -1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}


/* Transition

========================== */

.switch-label,
.switch-handle {
  transition: All 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: All 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: All 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: All 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="field">
  <label>send an email?</label>
  <label class="switch">
<input class="switch-input" type="checkbox" id="email" name="email" value=" 
{{values.email}}"/>
<span class="switch-label" data-on="Yes" data-off="No"></span>
<span class="switch-handle"></span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a `label`, you have two options for the label to be valid. One is to wrap the `input` inside the `label`, like so:

```html
<label> Label text
  <input type="text … />
</label>
```

The other option is to use the `for` attribute on the `label`, meaning that when the label is clicked, the `id` matching the value of `for` is clicked.

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox" name="myCheckbox" value=" true" />
<label for="myCheckbox">Click the checkbox</label>
```

This is the option you should use for your non-wrapping `label` without a `for` attribute. Currently, it's invalid.

The other `label` (`.switch`) wraps the UI of the switch, and is not invalid. However, we can use the `for` attribute *in addition* to wrapping the switch contents, making both `label`s point to the same `id`. This is a hybrid approach to `label`s and is valid `HTML`.

[image]

Why would we do this? Because to show more contents, we'll need to move the checkbox containing the targeted `id` "up" a level in the DOM. Once we do this, we can use the `~` selector to show/hide more content based on the value of the checkbox.

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF 25px);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF 25px);
  border-radius: 18px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px white, inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.switch-input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.switch-label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: inherit;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #eceeef;
  border-radius: inherit;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.switch-label:before,
.switch-label:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -.5em;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-transition: inherit;
  -moz-transition: inherit;
  -o-transition: inherit;
  transition: inherit;
}

.switch-label:before {
  content: attr(data-off);
  right: 11px;
  color: #aaaaaa;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.switch-label:after {
  content: attr(data-on);
  left: 11px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  opacity: 0;
}

.switch-input:checked~.switch .switch-label {
  background: #0088cc;
  border-color: #0088cc;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.switch-input:checked~.switch .switch-label:before {
  opacity: 0;
}

.switch-input:checked~.switch .switch-label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.switch-handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF 40%, #f0f0f0);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 40%, #f0f0f0);
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.switch-handle:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -6px 0 0 -6px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF);
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
}

.switch-input:checked~.switch .switch-handle {
  left: 74px;
  box-shadow: -1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

/* Transition

========================== */

.switch-label,
.switch-handle {
  transition: All 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: All 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: All 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: All 0.3s ease;
}

.show-more-fields {
  display: none;
}

.switch-input:checked~.show-more-fields {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="field">
  <input class="switch-input" type="checkbox" id="email" name="email" value=" true" />
  <label for="email">send an email?</label>
  <label for="email" class="switch">
    <span class="switch-label" data-on="Yes" data-off="No"></span>
    <span class="switch-handle"></span>
  </label>
  <div class="show-more-fields">More content here</div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ybz0pcte/2/)

Comment: This is awesome thank you! What would I need to do if I wanted the show-more-fields to show certain fields based on a the value chosen in a dropdown menu?

Comment: @Zone188 In that case, you would need to attach a `<select>` to an `onchange` event and manually check for certain `<option>` values. There's no pure `CSS` way to accomplish this.

Comment: I Changed the jsFiddle and in that example I only want the Pizza Toppings field to show up if the option pizza is chosen. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you share your jsFiddle link with me?

Comment: @Zone188 Here you go (new [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9pcgbzL4/4/)). I added some `JavaScript` and some new rules at the bottom of the `CSS`. If you're cool with it, I'd appreciate if you accepted my answer.